# How to use facebook pagination in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pagination, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, cursors

Hi I have recently started coding for iOS.I am trying to get videos from facebook using the following code.

```
-(void)facebookGetVideos:(UIViewController*)vc completionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableArray*))completionBlock{
   __block NSMutableArray * itemArray;
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]

                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me/videos/uploaded"

                                  parameters:@{@"fields":@"source,description,thumbnail,title"}

                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,

                                          NSError *error) {
        if(error!=nil){
             NSLog(@"Error after fb dwnld %@",error);
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:vc.view animated:true];
            [self showAlert:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription viewController:vc];
        }else{

            NSLog(@"Results %@",result);
             itemArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
           // [itemArray addObject:[result valueForKey:@"data"]];
            itemArray =[result valueForKey:@"data"];

             completionBlock(itemArray);
        }
    }];

}
```

The response I am getting from there is as below:-

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            id = 1845903302379295;
            source = "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t43.1792-2/27475816_220074475216744_8742438766032977920_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjE1MDAsInJsYSI6MTAyNCwidmVuY29kZV90YWciOiJzdmVfaGQifQ%3D%3D&rl=1500&vabr=382&oh=d4c3f6028a979c5919fdd8e444e24179&oe=5A89882A";
        },
                {
            id = 1814936632142629;
            source = "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.14539-2/23925286_2650490725061654_2502749796398268416_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjU3NiwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic2QifQ%3D%3D&rl=576&vabr=320&oh=2fde1aea6eff33d8139ccb8fe7a33fd4&oe=5A8980C0";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        cursors =         {
            after = MTgxNDkzNjYzMjE0MjYyOQZDZD;
            before = MTg0NTkwMzMwMjM3OTI5NQZDZD;
        };
    };
}
```

I am trying to use this after before as parameters as below:-

```
-(void)afterValues:(NSString*)afterVal{


    NSDictionary * parameters =@{@"fields":@"source",@"after": afterVal};
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request1 = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                   initWithGraphPath:@"me/videos/uploaded"
                                   parameters:parameters
                                   HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request1 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                           id result,
                                           NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"after videos%@",result);


    }];
}
```

And getting the following as response:-

```
after videos{
    data =     (
    );
}
```

Can anyone please point out at my mistake.Any kind of help/suggestion or guidance in this directions would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you requested the manage_pages permission from the respective user through the login dialog? I think you see an empty result because of the missing permission.

Comment: Yes .@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_photos",@"user_videos"].These are the permissions that I have taken.

Comment: Yes but you can add like loginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"manage_pages"];

Comment: Sir, when I am trying to add @"manage_pages" permission.It crashes and says"read and write permissions cant be taken together".Can You please help me to resolve this and show how both permissions can be taken together?